# Is the "I before E" English spelling rule wrong more than it is right?

Tags: language

[image: Arr I before E]

> There are 923 words that break the "i before e" rule.  Only 44 words actually follow that rule.

This is a picture circulating right now, claiming that a huge majority of the words break the "i before e" rule, and that only a few actually follow it.

**Is the rule as often incorrect as the picture claims?**

> "I before E, except after C" is a mnemonic rule of thumb for English
>   spelling. If one is unsure whether a word is spelled with the sequence
>   ei or ie, the rhyme suggests that the correct order is ie unless the
>   preceding letter is c, in which case it is ei.

[Wikipedia link that explains the rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C)

Comment: Even a rule of thumb should have more use than not. If the rule is false 95% of the time, I wouldn't even call it a rule of thumb.

Comment: That is very specific, and I am pretty sure that is wrong. I'd rather see the spirit of the claim questioned than detailed data.

Comment: @Sancho Oxford's dictionary should be fine. Question is which branch of English it is. I'd be fine no matter if it is British or American English.

Comment: 923 words breaking it, and 44 obeying it, would suggest that remembering how to do spelling is easy - just do the opposite of the rule!

Comment: According to one episode of [**Qi**](http://old.qi.com/tv/), The rule has been removed from  the OED (?) for precisely the reason that it’s useless.

Comment: I saw a version of the I before E rule, that was a bit more complex, and probably a bit more correct. http://www.spelling.org/free/instructional/ie_rule.htm

Comment: I believe this question is much harder to answer than simply examining a dictionary. You would also need to take into account word frequency. If there are thousands of "ei" words that you've never even heard of before that could obviously skew the results.

Comment: The rule I learned was *"'i' before 'e' except after 'c' or when sounded as AY as in neighbor and weigh."* Still fails on some borrow words (especially from German) but works very well as far as I can tell. Not my lookout if you learned an incomplete version of the rule. I see that @Wertilq's version covers the German derived words and some of the even odder cases.

Comment: I'm also curious what exactly the "skeptical" claim is here, but note that I don't think this "Rule" is actually taught anymore, as there are too many exceptions to reliably memorize.

Comment: @Wertilq's link seems to have moved to http://www.avko.org/reference/ie_rule.htm

Comment: One needn't be omniscient to see that the rule is inefficient. Science is sufficient for proficient and conscientious fanciers to see that the rule is deficient in our society.

Comment: @dmckee There's more to the rule: *" ... and on holidays, in March, and April and May. And you're always wrong no matter what you say."*

Comment: another way to count it is by prevalence of the words in normal writing. Is the "rule" more often applicable to the words most people are likely to use or not? is likely to be far more interesting to your average person than whether some number derived from a dictionary count is higher or lower than some other number.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It won't be possible to skeptically analyze whether or not the rule is useful. I will stick to analysis of the factual claim. I'm assuming that the "i before e" rule is exactly as you've quoted from the Wikipedia article.

**The claim in the image is false.**

In the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/), there are 8161 words that involve the letters *i* and *e* adjacent to each other.

To **follow the rule**, they would have to occur in the order "ie", unless they are preceded by the letter "c", in which case they must occur in the order "ei".

- Words that have *ie*, not after *c* (ambience, achieved): [5232](http://www.oed.com/search?browseType=sortAlpha&case-insensitive=true&f_0=Headword&f_1=Headword&nearDistance=1&o_1=NOT&ordered=false&page=53&pageSize=100&q_0=*ie*&q_1=*cie*&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch)
- Words that have *cei* (apperceive, ceiling): [182](http://www.oed.com/search?browseType=sortAlpha&case-insensitive=true&f_0=Headword&nearDistance=1&ordered=false&page=2&pageSize=100&q_0=*cei*&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch)

To **break the rule**, they would have to occur in the order "ei" without being preceded by a "c" or appear in the order "ie" while being preceded by a "c".

- Words that have *ei*, not after a *c* (abaeile, abeigh): [2423](http://www.oed.com/search?browseType=sortAlpha&case-insensitive=true&f_0=Headword&f_1=Headword&nearDistance=1&o_1=NOT&ordered=false&page=25&pageSize=100&q_0=*ei*&q_1=*cei*&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch)
- Words that have *cie* (abortifacient, ancient): [384](http://www.oed.com/search?browseType=sortAlpha&case-insensitive=true&f_0=Headword&nearDistance=1&ordered=false&page=4&pageSize=100&q_0=*cie*&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch)

So, among all *ei* or *ie* words in the Oxford English Dictionary, **5414 words follow the rule of thumb, and 2807 break the rule**.

EDIT: The picture is similar when taking word frequency in to account. In a list of ["the top 5,000 words in American English"](http://www.wordfrequency.info/):

Those that **follow the rule**:

- Words that have *ie*, not after *c*: 72
- Words that have *cei* : 6

Those that **break the rule**

- Words that have *ei*, not after a *c*: 19
- Words that have *cie*: 10

So, among these most frequent words there are **78 supporting the rule, and 29 against**.

Comment: Sancho, where are these numbers from?

Comment: From the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: Really, what page? :-) Where did you get these numbers...

Comment: Whether this confirms or denies the claim depends on whether it is talking about the rule as a whole (5414 follow > 2807 break), or just the exception for "c" (182 follow < 384 break).

Comment: Might still be worth mentioning that according to your numbers, "I before E" without exceptions would be a better rule.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I used the online interface to the dictionary to search for the relevant letter combinations. I added links to the searches that I used.

Comment: @hammar, That may be true, but I'd rather stick to analyzing the claim, rather than suggesting improvements.

Comment: The rule is right more often than it is wrong, except for the c rule, but the picture didn't mention the c rule. Is there a big difference in american english, and british english?

Comment: @Wertilq The differences between American and British English spellings occasionally involve this rule (aging vs. ageing). So, American spellings (aging) may break the rule less often than British spellings (ageing).

Comment: @Wertilq Where it says "the i before e rule" it means the rule, "i before e except after c". I'm not sure exactly where it gets the numbers from but it seems that: (1) the "923 words that break" is referring to 'cie' words (384 according to OED); (2) the "44 words that follow" is referring to 'cei' words (182).

Comment: I will also add that if **one third of words break the rule**, while it technically works for more words than not, it's a pretty lousy and unreliable rule!

Comment: the only problem with this answer is words taken from foreign languages are included and they tend to follow the rules of their parent language.

Comment: All English words came from "foreign" languages. Brythonic, Saxon, Old Norse and others are all Greek to me. QED.

Comment: Implicit in that rule is that "ie" is used to make the long-e sound (-ee-).  When I was taught the rule there was a second clause ... 'or as in "AY" as in "neighbour" or "weigh"'. With this clause the performance of the rule is much better.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat it would also depend on *which* words follow the rule - if the *ei* words are far less common in terms of actual usage than the *ie* words, then the rule would still be useful.

Comment: Just did a quick search of word frequency lists and it does appear like the "correctly following the rule" is far more prevalent than the opposition.

Comment: "And what about Or when sounding as 'ā' as in Neighbor and Weigh"?

Comment: @Chad, While I agree that it would be good to see those statistics, they'd be more difficult to analyze. Letter order can be checked with simple regular expressions, while vowel sounds are much more complicated. :)

Comment: From what I've found, the image comes from... here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duqlZXiIZqA&app=desktop

Comment: Well, if you show us those 19 words (of the top 5,000) with *ei* not after *c* perhaps we can check their pronunciation.